# Heat Equation Solution in One Dimension (x, t)

Tags: pde, numerical-analysis, python

We're currently solving the heat equation as a part of the PDE sequence in class.

We've been given the formula:$$T(i, n+1) = T(i,n)+\alpha \left [\frac{T(i+1,n)-2 T(i, n)+T(i-1,n)}{\Delta x^2} \right ] \quad \Delta t$$
I've got boundary conditions handled. They aren't the problem.

The problem here is, if one notices, $\alpha$, $\Delta x^2$, and $\Delta t$ are all permanent constants throughout the number of iterations. Thus, they can be pre-evaluated. There's just that one problem where, if the value of $\frac {\alpha \Delta t}{\Delta x^2}$ becomes larger than 0.5, I start running into problems with the equation itself. One can see that when that term = 0.5:
$$\begin{matrix}
100 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
100 & 50 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
100 & 50 & 25 & 0 & 0\\
100 & 67.5 & 25 & 12.5 & 0
\end{matrix}$$

Here, every row represents a new time instance, and every column is a new discrete x-position element along the 'thin rod' that I am considering.

The moment the $\frac {\alpha \Delta t}{\Delta x^2}$ goes below 0.5, however, we are 'good', meaning that this problem ceases to occur, but the propagation of temperature through the 'thin rod' is still really slow, even with a really high temperature at one end, which is held constant.

Is the equation provided wrong? Or am I misunderstanding something? Is there some error in sign somewhere?

Edit: This is indeed a class assignment, but given the nature of the situation, I am inclined to think that it is either my understanding that is fundamentally flawed (beyond the code, just the concept) or I've simply been given the wrong equation.

Edit 2: Error in evaluating the matrix. Corrected that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've stumbled upon a common problem with explicit schemes. This is a common issue with numerical analysis and it's called the Courant–Friedrichs–Lewy (CFL) condition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courant%E2%80%93Friedrichs%E2%80%93Lewy_condition).

In short, you have to adjust your time step size and the spatial discretization in order to meet this condition, which very much depends on the physical situation.  Usually, the time step is adjusted, since adaptive meshing (or remeshing and mapping your solution) is somewhat costly.

Conceptually, this condition occurs because the "communication" between nodes becomes much slower than the "motion" of the solution.  This means that the temperature, let's think the diffusion of phonons for a more physical conceptualization, moves over multiple cells per time step.  What you want is a condition such that the phonons travel through one cell over many time steps.

The CFL condition is a required condition only for explicit numerical schemes and is a necessary condition in both convection and diffusion problems.

Comment: I rather liked the 'Congratulations' pre-edit. It made me feel good for realizing that I'd run into this condition which I didn't even know was a thing. Many thanks. However, I am still stuck with the problem of the problem never progressing in terms of temperature gradients through the thin rod.

Comment: Hah, I thought it might have seemed a bit sarcastic and condescending, but I do think it's really one of the graduating moments when you realized this.

Comment: It is. Who would've know that the entire thing diverges (is that the correct word here?) given that the constant term exceeds 0.5. I am, however, unfortunately still stuck with a rod that barely conducts any heat.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten a step.

The equation is:
$$T(i, n+1) = T(i,n)+\alpha \left [\frac{T(i+1,n)-2 T(i, n)+T(i-1,n)}{\Delta x^2} \right ] \quad \Delta t$$

And you are evaluating:
$$T(i, n+1) = \alpha \left [\frac{T(i+1,n)-2 T(i, n)+T(i-1,n)}{\Delta x^2} \right ] \quad \Delta t$$

Comment: It appears that you are correct. How utterly stupid of me. I shall edit the matrix and see if that makes a difference, thank you. I'll accept the answer if I see that this works.

Comment: It's a remarkably easy mistake to make, which is why I recognised it... We only think about the part of the problem that's non-trivial to solve.

Comment: Jesse's answer enlightened me about what this particular problem is called. As helpful as that is, I still run into the problem of temperature conduction 'stagnating' after a certain time. Thus, one end stays at 0, while the other stays at 1000, and I make no progress. This is rather depressing.

Comment: If the boundary conditions specify that one side is zero and one is 1000, that is actually the expected result, I would think. Gradually converging onto a straight line between the two boundary conditions is certainly normal for the heat equation, and this makes sense - heat equalizes over time.

Comment: What do you mean by stagnating?  What are your boundary conditions?  It looks like you have a Dirichlet at the top and right = 0 and a Neuman on the bottom.

Comment: That's correct.  If you don't have heat generation and you also have constant thermophysical properties, you will have a straight line between two Dirichlet boundary conditions.

Comment: The physics program at my university is a bit off. In that, I've never actually looked at PDEs before this class, and our ODE/PDE class actually comes after this computational physics class, yet this class presupposes PDE knowledge. So those terms do not make as much sense to me as I'd like them to. All I know here is that temp at one end is 1000, and the temp gradient at the other end gradually tends to 0.

Comment: And no, the 'far end' boundary condition is that the gradient of temperature (please forgive the lack of MathJax, I am rather ill-versed in it) remain 0. So the end does get hotter (in fact, my job is to find out when it gets too hot to hold), however, there is no 'heat flux' (prof said this, I assume it means temperature gradient slope) at the far end boundary.

Comment: I see.  So, you have a condition where you have an open boundary condition.  In this case, you have to artificiality update the boundary to the neighbouring terms.  How you do this depends on whether you're using a staggered or co-located numerical grid.  This is outside of the question you originally asked, I think.

Comment: It is, and it appears that I will have to look at a few dozen Youtube videos again to understand this. Nevertheless, I appreciate all the answers and comments so far. It appears that I need to do quite a bit more reading before I can get on with this.